# hybrid auth for zf1

Tags: php, zend-framework, hybridauth

I am a newbee to zf and my project requires to integrate hybrid auth social login with zf1.
 Unfortunately I could find any hybrid auth for zf1. can anyone please help me for this? 
Struggling for this past two days.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do authentication in Zend you should review [Zend_Auth documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.html) to make sure you understand the how things works...

To implement custom authentication in Zend you will have to create your own authentication adapter and pass instance of your adapter to `Zend_Auth::authenticate`. Implementing a custom adapter is very easy, you only have to implement one interface with one function and define your constructor - see [`example of custom adapter in Zend documentation`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.introduction.html#zend.auth.introduction.adapters) and [`example of how to pass adapter to Zend_Auth instance`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.introduction.html#zend.auth.introduction.using).

I am not familiar with hybridauth but looks like [hybridauth already has bunch of plugins](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/plugins.html) including ZF2. Also, take a look at existing [plain PHP hybridauth examples in the repo](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/tree/master/examples).

Comment: Hi @Alex, thanx for response. I am clear with zend auth and my project is build in zendframework 1.12.3 which makes it more difficult to find help since all the plugins and latest docs comes for zf2. I used TBS plugin for authentication in zf1 made few changes in it to fetch user contatc list. Now I am struggling to find a way to send app request to yahoo,google & facebook networks for the loggedin in user